# How do you calculate the market value of a bond position?

Tags: bond, pricing

I got this question in an interview - and I answered it in terms of DVO1 and MTM positions in our Order management system. How would you have answered this question ?

```
How do you calculate the market value of a bond position? You can assume you 
have all required data points available which are necessary to calculate market 
value (e.g. from your firm's OMS, holdings/positions database tables, etc). 
We are not asking how to discount future cashflows to calculate 
present value.
```

Comment: price times quantity plus accrued interest

Comment: which also = dirty price times quantity.

Comment: times any factor, if the bond is amortizing or PIK.